# Linq To Entities exception does not recognize the method and cannot be translated into store expression

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities

Can somebody please give an explanation to why I am getting this error with my LINQ code?

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method  'System.String
>   GenerateHashWithSalt(System.String, System.String)'method and this
>   method cannot be translated into a store expression.

```
var query = (from u in context.Users
                         where 
                         u.Password ==  
                          GenerateHashWithSalt(password, GetUserID(username))
                         select u).Count();
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are trying to pass a method to EF which tries to convert that method to known SQL command.
SQL doesn't know about `GenerateHashWithSalt(System.String, System.String)` 
You should first assign the result to a variable then generate your Linq to Entity Query.

Example

```
var hashedPassword = GenerateHashWithSalt(password, GetUserID(username));
var user = (from p in Users
        where p.Password == hashedPassword
        select p).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, I done exactly what you suggested and it works fine. Very nice and clean explanation.

Comment: And what happens if I can't get the value until the query time? I have the same error but this is my query:

`(From user As UserInfo In context.UserInfo Where Membership.GetUser(user.login).IsApproved = False Or user.isValidated = False).ToList`

Answer (score 0):

LINQ providers look at your *expression tree*, and try to generate equivalent TSQL (etc) from that. This only works for *recognised* methods, or *recognised* expression scenarios.

It can't look at an arbitrary method in your C# code and execute that at the database.

However! You could simplify the query for it:

```
var hash = GenerateHashWithSalt(password, GetUserID(username);
var count =context.Users.Count(u => u.Password == hash);
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's a [shortcoming of LINQ to Entities](http://blog.dreamlabsolutions.com/post/2008/11/17/LINQ-Method-cannot-be-translated-into-a-store-expression.aspx)

As Jethro says, and the link above shows an example, you need to convert it to something that SQL knows about.